# Extract the diagonal element of the matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, diagonal

I need to extract the elements of the main diagonal of the matrix:

I have tried the following **solution:**

```
[U S V]= svd (T)
lambda= reshape(S',[],1);
```

But I have got the column vector with all elements  but I need only the elements of the main diagonal

I also have tried:

```
[U S V]= svd (T)
lambda = diag(S);
```

But It doesn't"t work

Can someone help me to extract the elements of the diagonal?

Comment: `lambda = diag(S)`? Why the cell-indexing with `n` (which you don't show us how you defined it)?

Comment: @Adriaan it was only a part of the code. this operation is only a part

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just be able to use `diag` directly on `S`

```
lambda = diag(S);
```

From the docs:

> `D = diag(v)` returns a square diagonal matrix with the elements of vector `v` on the main diagonal.

Comment: if I write diag (T), I get the diagonal element of the T. But I need the diagonal element of the S matrix from svd of T

Comment: I need to extract only the elements of the ain diagonal of the matrix

Comment: @Noel then you need to edit your question to include a [mcve], because "it doesn't work" is not a clear enough problem statement, `lambda = diag(S)` will return the diagonal elements of `S`.