# Sum of diagonals in matrice nxn matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum, diagonal

How do you calculate the sum of the elements of both diagonals in a matrix nxn but making sure that the middle element, if there is one, is not counted twice in the sum. Thank you!

Comment: You calculate the sum of the diagonal elements like you normally would, and then you subtract the value of the middle element once since it was counted twice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extract the diagonal element of the matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57706629/extract-the-diagonal-element-of-the-matrix)

Comment: Welcome to the site! For future questions, note that you are expected to show some effort, typically by posting the code you have attempted

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way that avoids having two separate cases for `n` odd (the central entry should not be counted twice) and `n` even (there is no central entry). It uses a logical index built from the identity matrix and its reflection:

```
M = magic(5); % example data
ind = logical(eye(size(M))); % logical index for diagonal ...
ind = ind | flipud(ind); % ... and anti-diagonal
result = sum(M(ind)); % indexing with a logical index gives a vector
```

Comment: That’s pretty clever!